# Looking for SessionPreset resolution and bit rate information for iPhone4S and iPad1/2

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm looking around for SessionPreset's resolution and bit rate information of iPhone4S, iPad and iPad2.

In [Apple's AVFoundation document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html), there is no mention about 4S and iPad1/2.

Please tell me where to look, or way to list supported presets(and its resolution).
Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

[AVFoundation CheatSheet](http://sh3ng.com/2011/05/ios-device-recording-resolution/), iPhone 3G,iPhone 3GS,iPhone 4 (Back),iPhone 4 (Front)

Comment: The link to the cheat sheet appears to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find out information. So I've examined them one by one.
Here's the result.

(I've checked only back camera, values of iPhone 3GS,4 is lent from cheat sheet.)
(3GS/4/4S are iPhone, P2/P3 are iPad, T4 is touch 4th)

```
Preset | 3GS(B)    | 4(B)      | 4S(B)     | P2(B)    | P3(B)     | T4(B)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Photo  | 2048x1536 | 2592x1936 | 3264x2448 | 960x720  | 2592x1936 | 960x720
High   | 640x480   | 1280x720  | 1920x1080 | 1280x720 | 1920x1080 | 1280x720
Medium | 480x360   | 480x360   | 640x480   | 640x480  | 640x480   | 640x480
Low    | 192x144   | 192x144   | 640x480   | 640x480  | 640x480   | 640x480
```

I don't have confidence about Low/Medium value of iPhone4S/iPad2,3/Touch4th. I think Medium(480x360) and Low(192x144) are same in all devices...

Comment: I'll report front camera soon.